# Jquery Uncaught ReferenceError: i4 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:1)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making add cart using localstorage, here I am trying to show cart items and delete using key. when I try to delete item by passing parameter in jquery.
It shows this error in console

```
    index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: i4 is not defined
        at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
    removeitem(1,i4);//i4 is not defined, it is key in localstorage.
```

This is my pop up function in jquery for showing cart items and the error is in button onclick function passing parameter i.e trying to pass key in :

```
onclick ='removeitem("+i+','+keyitem+")'   



    $("#cartPOP").click(function(){
              var count = 1;
              var i =1;
              var k = 0;
              var keyitem = key;
              var qunatTotal = 0;
              var total = 0;
              Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function(key){

              var item = "delitem"+i;
              var ffprice = "ffprice"+i;
              var fpvalueid = "fpvalueid"+i;
              var selectid = "selectid"+i;
              var trcount = "trcount"+i;
              keyitem = String(key);
              console.log("items...."+localStorage.getItem(key));
              var myobj =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
              console.log("keyyy...."+key);
              $("#tab1").append("<tr id = '"+trcount+"'>
                <td>"+count+"</td><td   id='fname'>"+myobj.food_name+"</td>
                <td>"+myobj.quantity+"</td>  
               <input value="+myobj.food_price+" id='"+fpvalueid+"'     type='hidden' />
               <td id="+ffprice+">Rs "+myobj.food_price+"<br>
               <small style='color: red;'> Included 5% gst and packing  charge</small>
                </td>
                <td>
               <button onclick ='removeitem("+i+','+keyitem+")'  id="+item+" class='fa fa-remove' style='font-size:20px;color:red'>delItem</button>
              </td>
              </tr>");
               count++;
               i++;
               k++;
              });
        });
```

I keep this removeitem function outside scope of jquery but inside script tag

```
function removeitem(x, key)
{
  var id = "trcount"+x;
  console.log("remove_test>>>  "+id);
  console.log("key>>>  "+key);
  localStorage.removeItem(key);//here i am trying to remove cart using key
  var tt = document.getElementById(id);
  document.getElementById('tab1').removeChild(tt); 
}
```

I have these questions :

How can I pass localstorage key in my above code for deleting item?
Why I am getting the above error when using this code inside jquery append function for button event? but when I remove keyitem and pass only one argument in removeitem function that is `i`, ther was no error but my remove cart functionality is not working properly.

```
<button onclick ='removeitem("+i+','+keyitem+");' id="+item+" class='fa fa-remove' style='font-size:20px;color:red'>delItem</button>
```

Please suggest me, I tried many ways but not working.

Comment: let's try this one:

`$("#cartPOP").on('click', function(){` ...

Comment: Aside from the fact you should avoid using inline event handlers, you are missing quotes around the string value. `onclick='removeitem("+i+",\""+keyitem+"\")'`

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi no it cant work my error is in inside this function of append Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(function(key){ .... <button onclick="removeitems(i, key)"/> ... }); that key is not defined when trying to pass

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks now it is working, i was trying that, my quotes around the string value was wrong that why it cud not work. Thank you!!